# procedural generation of road with moving car

Tags: windows-7, software-development, simulation, animation, game-development

Target Platform: Windows 7 64 Bit (SP1 - with latest updates installed)

I am a Direct2D/C++ programmer and I want to experiment the **procedural 3D animation** of a street based on a text file. In the text file, I would be having something like this,

```
Length (in meters)  Curvature(Angle)     Uphill (Angle)       Downhill(Angle)

1000                     -                   -                      20°

300                      20° (left)          -                       -

500                      5° (right)          30°                     -
```

This means, for 1 kilometre the street is straight with 20° downhill. The next 300 meters the street has 20° curve (no uphill and no downhill). After that for the next 500 meters the street has 5° towards right direction with 30° uphill. **So, programmatically I need to generate road details (terrain).**

As for beginning, the street does not have any landscape (no trees, no buildings, no traffic signs, etc.) and only one car is moving inside the lane in a variable speed. I need to see the car movement using chase cam view.

which software/game engine/tool/technology/programming language is recommended to implement my requirements?